# SSRS 2008 R2 - Lookup from subreport

Tags: reporting-services

is it possible to do a lookup in SSRS 2008 report from a Subreport? if so, can someone tell me how please?

Answer (score 0):

No, the lookup function won't go beyond the scope of the report. Your question isn't very clear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish (which would be helpful) but I'll try to guess.

If you're looking to pass some values to the subreport from the parent's dataset you could check [this blog post about doing that](http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasthedeuce/archive/2009/11/13/136287.aspx), though I haven't tried it myself. You could also use a shared dataset to avoid rewriting your queries if you need to use the dataset again in both of the reports.

According to [this msdn social thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e1fc8e37-781e-4e96-b582-529d0befb400) it doesn't appear to be possible to pass a value to the parent report from the subreport. However, [another thread on sqlservercentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic834917-1063-1.aspx) seems to have some promise but it didn't seem to work for everyone. Once again, I haven't tried it myself.

Good luck, and let us know if anything works!

Comment: Thank you... I thought the question was pretty clear.  We all have to use lookup in SSRS from time to time, I am in a situation where I need to do a look up from a sub report...Get a value from the sub report and display it on the main report. Both the reports use completely different datasets from different (complicated stored procedures) sources.   Passing parameters and displaying the sub report is the easy part.  I will give your links a try and update what I have been able to achieve.  Cheers